# Command \LT@p@ftntext has changed

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I get a warning in my output saying

hyperref.sty "Command \LT@p@ftntext has changed."

I am using an up to date installation of texlive on linux.  It is something to do with the package glossaries, here is a MWE to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,fleqn,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    hello world
\end{document}
```

If I comment out \usepackage[toc]{glossaries}, the error goes away.  Is it something to just ignore or can I fix the error?

Thank you in advance,

Martyn

Comment: you can ignore it for now. A change in longtable need to be synced with hyperref. I just uploaded a new hyperref version with the fix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.